# How to create a circuit to turn off LED when switch is "ON" and turn on when "OFF"

Tags: mosfet

[image]how to create a circuit to TURN OFF LED WHEN SWITCH IS "ON" AND TURN OFF LED WHEN SWITCH IF "OFF" for 12v input?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvrBSU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Basic schematic for original poster to edit.*

Comment: Easiest way is to place the switch across the LED. This may not be what you want but you need to add more information to your question.

Comment: If you want to turn it off when the switch is on and when the switch is off, simply don't connect it. Please revise your question to remove the ALL CAPS and clarify what you are asking for.

Comment: Shouting in title removed. No schematic supplied so question not really answerable.

Comment: Hi Dwayne and Tom, Please refer a sample scenario above.

Comment: There is no power supply (battery or mains) in your circuit schematic so your LED will never light. At the very least you need a battery, as switch, a resistor and an LED. These should be wired in series to create a *circuit* so that current can flow around the circuit when the switch is closed.

Comment: just assume the + and - terminal in the push button switch will also my input source...

Comment: We can't assume because our assumptions might be wrong.  You've asked a question on an *engineering* site. That means proper designs and calculations. There is a button on the editor toolbar for the built-in schematic editor. It has symbols for batteries, switches, resistors and LEDs. Draw a proper (simple) schematic of what you are trying to describe and you will get good answers.

Comment: I've added a basic schematic to your post. Please edit this to explain what you are asking about. The component values are the defaults. Edit to suit your application.

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/bhp/normally-closed-switch

Comment: Hello, i just want to clarify that the push button on the image is just an illustration and for us to know the source came from that button when it being pushed then the wire is cut otherwise it gives a complete circuit... that is why i need your help guys to invert the action of that push button OFF when is not pushed and ON when it pushed.. btw way thank you guys i hope you understand what i need...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an easier way would be to use a pull-up resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCns7Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the switch is "off" (open, like displayed in the schematic), the voltage source provides current to the led through the resistor, so it turns it on.
Assuming the LED's forward voltage is 2V, forward current is 20mA, the calculation for the resistor is as following:

V1 = I*R1 + Vf

R1 = (V1 - Vf)/I = (12-2)/20m = 500Ohm

When the switch is "on" (closed), the current provided by the voltage source V1 flows to ground, so the LED does not turn on. Or you can think of it as the anode of the LED having 0V, like it's cathode, therefore not turning on.

Answer (score 8):

You have added the tag "mosfet" so I assume you want to turn the LED on and off with a FET. I am also guessing that you want the LED to turn ON when the switch is OFF.  Here's one way to do it:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmzNgH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When SW1 is off, MOSFET M1 receives +12V on its Gate via R2. This causes the FET to turn on and light the LED. When SW1 is on it applies 0V to the Gate so the FET turns off.

When the switch is on a small current of 12V/100k = 120uA flows through R2. If this is too much then you can increase its resistance. However the higher the resistance the more sensitive the circuit will be to electrical or electromagnetic interference and leakage currents when the switch is off.

Comment: Thak bruce for your answer...

Comment: Hi bruce, i added some information to my question above

Comment: @Blacksheep: By accepting Bruce's answer you are indicating that your question has been answered. Why are you adding more information to your question?

Comment: Bruce can you make a circuit without using a mosfet?

Comment: If you don't want to use a transistor then see Eran's answer (note that it draws 24mA when the LED is off, more than when it is on). Or use a switch with contacts that open when it is operated.